# What is the use of cash?

Tags: sunset-overdrive

In the game there seem to be 2 currencies. Overcharge and cash.

Overcharge seems to be used for pretty much everything but after reaching credits, I don't think I've seen an instance of using cash for anything.

So what is the use of cash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it's only for buying clothing, as [IGN](https://www.ign.com/wikis/sunset-overdrive/Currency) says:

> Money can be found in a variety of ways, but it only has one use: Buying clothing and outfits from Calista after you meet her following the A New Friend mission.

Comment: Oh lol, talked to her once to pick an outfit and never talked to her again. Guess thats why I missed it.